# Android global variable not working in Service

Tags: android, global-variables

I'm perplexed why I cannot access my global variables from my service.  I can access them from other activities just fine....

global var class:

```
public class Global extends Application {
private static final String TAG = "Global Class";

int test;     

public int getTest()
{
    return test;
}
```

Main Activity I use this test code:

```
Global appState = ((Global)getApplication()); //Context());
appState.setTest(555);
Log.e("SETTEST",new Integer(appState.getTest()).toString());
```

Result is 555

Another activity I use the same code:

```
Global appState = ((Global)getApplication()); //Context());
Log.e("SETTEST",new Integer(appState.getTest()).toString());
```

Result is 555

FInally in my service, I use the same code as above:

```
Global appState = ((Global)getApplication()); //Context());
Log.e("SETTEST",new Integer(appState.getTest()).toString());
```

and I get big, fat 0 back.

Please help.  I've spent 3 hours on this so far.
I've tried using  getApplication, and getApplicationContext

Also, manifest looks like this:

```
...
<application android:icon="@drawable/signal" android:label="@string/app_ name" android:name="<absolute path>.util.Global">


<service
    android:name=".util.MyService"
    android:process=":MyService" 
    android:icon="@drawable/airplane"
    android:label="@string/service_name"
    >
</service>
```

**I just tried using a singleton class as well according to this post.  same troubles as above:

[Android - Global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658980/android-global-variables?rq=1)

Comment: Try to pass them using Shared Preferences..I hope it will work.

Comment: Is your service running locally or remote? Post the manifest for your service

Comment: this was just simple test code.  i'm passing a large array of custom objects...i'm not sure if shared prefs is the way to go-correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: good question - its running locally (at least I think so). i posted the entry

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your service is running remotely because you've got this:

```
android:process=":MyService"
```

in the manifest definition for the service.

This means that it is running an a completely separate process. You can't share global variables using static variables that way.

If you don't need your service to run in a separate process, then just remove the "android:process" line and you'll be good.

Comment: they should have warn people, or I missed sth.

Comment: I had that issue, and this fixed it perfectly. What is the benefit to run application in multiprocess?

Comment: @EspeH We use multiple processes to get around the memory limits of single processes on older devices. By splitting the application across multiple processes we are able to use more memory. Also, if you split your application you can gain a measure of robustness because if one part crashes the other part continues to run. These are just 2 examples of why you might want to use multiple processes.