# Why my service is force close?

Tags: android, android-service

I write an app and service on android. My app and service are speaking each other.Everything is fine even I press home button or back button and exit my app, still my service is running and doing its job.
But the problem is :
in the attached screenshot from my phone. When I long press home button there is a layout about recently open apps,if I press clear all and delete my app my service is forcing close,
I mean even I clear all apps on phone I want to my service  be still running.

**here is my code:**

```
public class myservice  extends Service  { 
    String sourceFileUri;
     
 
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       }
   
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here..
   
    }
    @Override 
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         upLoadServerUri= intent.getStringExtra("upLoadServerUri"); 
          try {
         UploaderFoto ups = new UploaderFoto( sourceFileUri  );//this upload image to server
         ups.execute(execute) ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
       
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { 
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    

     
public class UploaderFoto  extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null; 
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";   
     
    String sourceFileUri ; 
    String upLoadServerUri ; 
    String fileName  ; 
     
    public UploaderFoto( String sourceFileUri  ) {  
        this.sourceFileUri=sourceFileUri; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        mNotificationHelper.createNotification();   
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 
        
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int serverResponseCode = 0;
        try {
 
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy

            // Use a post method.
            //I set here conn parameters

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_name\";filename=\""
                + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            int streamSize = (int) sourceFile.length();
            bufferSize = xxx;

            buffer = new byte[streamSize];
            int sentBytes=0;
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 
            while (bytesRead > 0) {   
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            // bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
 
            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();  
            fileInputStream.close();  
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
             Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       
            
        return result;

    } // protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
   
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
         
            try {
                stopSelf();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
                
        
    }  

} 
}
```

**here is my manifest:**

```
  <service
            android:name="com.xx.yy.myservice" 
            android:enabled="true" 
            android:process =":remote"
             >
   </service>
```

**here is my error :**

```
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): Process: com.xx.yy:remote, PID: 12068
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.xx.yy.myservice@42faa538 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2726)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at com.xx.yy.myservice.onStartCommand(upload_service.java:42)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2709)
03-28 07:40:58.937: E/AndroidRuntime(12068):    ... 10 more
```

**my service purpose:file upload**

**when long press clear all this(I press clear all when my service is already started)**
[image]

**IMPORTANT**
*I long press and clear all apps after the service started*

**UPDATE**
`when I write` *return START_NOT_STICKY;* `end of the` *onstartcommand* `it does not give any error but it does not upload the file too, I want it run in the background even I close and clear the main app.`

Comment: post your service code that too why are you running your service in a diffrent process??

Comment: I do not want to close my service close when the main app is closed. because of this.

Comment: @Amiya my service code?

Comment: post your service class code

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Your service wont close it will run in the background until you call stopSelf() or stop()

Comment: But it gives error if my parent app is cleared :)

Comment: @Amiya  I edit my answer please look

Comment: @raj  I edit my answer please look

Comment: @kalyanpvs  is it bad way to use :remote?

Comment: are you passing intent extras with button click??

Comment: This cannot be your code because `upLoadServerUri` isn't defined (so it won't compile). With code shown, `intent` is null and that's the issue

Comment: your problem is very simple your service is not getting value of upLoadServerUri= intent.getStringExtra("upLoadServerUri");

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar With using remote process its diffcult to communicate with other process take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657192/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-running-a-service-in-diffrent-proce

Comment: @RC. this is my code but I dont copy all of my code because it is complex and hard to read , so everything is fine , the code runs perfectly but the problem when I longpreess menu button and clear all , then it gives error

Comment: @raj yes in main activity when I click button I put extras and then I getextras in service he code runs perfectly but the problem when I longpreess menu button and clear all , then it gives error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent the service from being terminated from app manager or recent apps.

Why you get the NPE exception is that `intent` is `null` in `onStartCommand()`. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29):

> This may be null if the service is being restarted after its process has gone away, and it had previously returned anything except `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`

Comment: thanks for answer, I do not understand exactly sorry about that, just I write **return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;** enf of the *onstartcommand* method?
and the problem is when the service starting to run and then I long press and clear all apps, I mean I think it is already exit *onstartcommand* and go to upload asyntask method right?

Comment: hi again, I tried **START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY**  but the result is same

Comment: When I write **START_NOT_STICKY** it does not give any error, I understand the problem, but why the I clear main app why the service is stopped ? I want it run still in background

Answer (score 0):

Check for the NPE under `onStartCommand()` and apply null checks or put them in try block. Service may be stoped or kill by Android Dalvik and if the service is `START_STICKY` use

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

it's again started by the Android Dalvik and will be run even after the app closed.

Comment: I tried it is same result, but when I tried **START_NOT_STICKY ** it does not give any error but it is not uploading the file too, I want to my service does not affect when the main app is clear in my screenshot(when I close my app everything is fine)

Comment: Android Dalvik will start your service once if the device switched on or service has been stoped by Android Dalvik, But once the service has been started it has to be run endlessly, By re-viewing your code your service get finished once you finished with uploading and not running continuously. That's the reason when you clear the app data, service has been finished. Hope it will resolve your problem. Just keep running your service by using a thread which continuously check for the upload url and uploads the data, and just loops while there is no url to upload.

Comment: sorry maybe I can not tell correctly, I mean if I clear all (in my screenshot) what is going on to my service? my app is closed I think but what is doing to the service? is it destroyed when it is trying to upload image?

Comment: Visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862882/service-does-not-restart-after-clear-memory-appwidget-crashes, Same problem.

Comment: thanks for comment , but is it same problem? ı cant use **registerServices** how can I implement this and this question is about widget receiver?

Comment: Start your service on boot receiver, and after installing your app restart your device. Maybe this is the reason. You can also check if your service is running or not and start it when you enter in your app. This will work in the case where user just install the app and start using it with out restart. Please do this and let me know.