# Singleton Room database in SyncAdapter to trigger LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-syncadapter, android-room

I'm struggling to use `Room` as singleton in my `SyncAdapter`. I use Kotlin.

My room class

```
@Database(entities = [(Product::class)], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun productDao(): ProductDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context) : AppDatabase =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(context.applicationContext)
                        .also {INSTANCE = it}
            }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
                Room
                        .databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                                AppDatabase::class.java, "database.db")
                        .allowMainThreadQueries()
                        .build()
    }

}
```

I retrieve database instance like this

```
val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)
```

And my issue is that I always get two different instances of `AppDatabase` in my activities and `SyncAdapter`. Though among activities `AppDatabase` object is indeed singleton `.AppDatabase_Impl@3c9ff34d`, and for each onPerformSync() the `AppDatabase` is singleton too `.AppDatabase_Impl@7d7718d`. 
But as you can see they are two different objects.
Can any one explain what I miss here?

On the other hand maybe I'm conceptually wrong in what I'm trying to achieve. Then any advice would be appreciated.

The point is to use `LiveData` to update UI components when new data is inserted from remote server via `SynAdapter`. In this case I have to use the same `productDao` object in `ViewModel/Activity` and in `SyncAdapter` in order to trigger LiveData on inserting new products, otherwise it won't be triggered.
So, to obtain the same `productDao` I must get the same(i.e. singleton) `AppDatabase`.

I know that this can be implemented using a `ContentProvider`, that is triggered automatically on inserting new data. But I really want to try new android architecture components. 
Or maybe using `ContentProvider` is the only correct way to implement this use-case?

Comment: Is your `SyncAdapter` in the same process as the MainThread? (This is something you define in the manifest)

Comment: No, my SyncAdapter uses android:process=":sync".
I guess I see what you mean: singleton is not shared between processes?

Comment: Yes that's could be the "only" problem. Let's try removing the `process` line and post the results back here.

Comment: Removing the definition of separate global process from manifest, i.e. `android:process=":sync"`, did the trick. 
And now I have the same database and dao objects across activities and sync provider. Thanks a lot for your help.
But are there any significant drawbacks in this solution - if I use only one application process?

Comment: I'll post a complete answer now, let me explain something ;)

Comment: I'd appreciate that. And it's interesting to use Dagger2 as an option as @sokarcreative suggested in his answer, but I think it will be the same issue because of separate :sync process.

Comment: Yes, Dagger2 is for DI, won't solve you problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want an easy communication between different `Threads` you need to be in the same process.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` you can specify an attribute called `android:process=":processName"` usable on **Activities**, **Services**(which relates to SyncAdapters), **Content Providers** and **Broadcast Receivers**, which can help you exceed the default limits of Heap (memory) for single process.

Those are the summarized PRO/CONS:

> Multi-process PRO: You have more memory to run your app and if a
>   process crashes it doesn't crash the other ones.
>
> Multi-process CONS:
>   It's a lot more difficult (but not impossible) to let the processes
>   communicate with each other but obviously you can't share the state between them (in your case the state is the singleton)

For a deep understanding, you should read [this article](https://medium.com/@rotxed/going-multiprocess-on-android-52975ed8863c) and [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20831979/2910520)

**My suggestion**: If your app is not so complex and you don't have memory problems I'll suggest you start with the single process approach. While if you want to decouple the SyncAdapter which update your data from the app, or at some point in the development you find bottlenecks or crashes related to the single-process, you could switch to multi-process, remove direct LiveData and use ContentProvider to communicate data changes.

Comment: But does it effect in any way how android shuts down my application? What I mean is that android can kill "heavy" process if it is not needed, i.e. I exited my app and android kills it in some time. 
But if my SyncAdapter runs in the same process where Application resides, does it mean that this process will never be killed and my app is always active in the background??

Comment: Anyway I accept your answer. You helped me a lot, thank you.
Further discussion is just for full understanding of trades.

Comment: This really depends on your needs. If you want to use the LiveData feature from the SyncAdapter you MUST put the SyncAdapter in the same process. If you want have more chances that the system won't kill your app, you can go with the multi-process approach and use the content provider to access the data. As I said this completely depends on what you want to achieve with your application

Comment: @akamuza I've updated my final suggestion, hope it is more clear now ^^

Comment: helped me alot. Thank you! It works if you remove the "android:process=":processName" from the SynService.

Answer (score 0):

Using dagger2 :

```
class MyApplication : Application(){

    val component: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(this)).build()
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var database : AppDatabase

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component.inject(this)
    }

}
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
        AppModule::class
))
interface AppComponent {
   fun inject(app: MyApplication)
}

@Module
class AppModule constructor(private val context: Context) {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesDatabase() = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "mydb.db").build()

}
```

From activity :

```
@Inject lateinit var mRoomDatabase: AppDatabase

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     (application as MyApplication).component.inject(this)
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use Dagger2, but it's too overwhelming for me as I'm novice to it and the main problem was that I could not inject `AppDatabase` in `SyncAdapter`. So can you explain , please, how can I inject into `SyncAdapter`.

Comment: If I understand well, what you need is a singleton database and using architecture component you want to listen changes from a dao class and refresh the associated adapter automattically, right ?

Comment: @sokarcreative He already successfully implemented a Singleton pattern, his problem was related to using a second process for the SyncAdapter. Dagger is not the solution to this specific problem (because probably he doesn't need all the complexity brought by Dagger for a single Singleton)

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. But changes are made from SyncAdapter thus I must have the same dao shared between sync adapter and a view model. But sync adapter us run in a separate process.

Comment: @MatPag ah ok, I understand now. Indeed Dagger2 didn't solve it :/